# Dyalog APL: What are the miracles? Trouble with + and range

Tags: apl, dyalog

I wonder why is Dyalog APL acting so strange?

```
      692.4 - 88 - 6.45 - 39.08 - 20 - 53
538.77 ⍝ Fail
      -/ 692.4 88 6.45 39.08 20 53
538.77 ⍝ Fail again
      692.4 - 88
604.4
604.4 - 6.45
597.95
597.95-39.08
558.87
558.87-20
538.87
538.87-53
485.87 ⍝ It's true!
```

But why? What's the problem with the Dyalog APL?

Comment: There is already an answer explaining why you get what you do. Ways to get the result you want include `((((692.4 - 88) - 6.45) - 39.08) - 20) - 53` and `692.4 - 88 + 6.45 + 39.08 + 20 + 53` and `692.4 - +/ 88 6.45 39.08 20 53` and `+/ 692.4 ¯88 ¯6.45 ¯39.08 ¯20 ¯53`. That is up to the precision of the underlying floating point representation (assuming `⎕FR` is `645`, meaning 64-bit _binary_ floating point (a.k.a. IEEE double-precision binary floating point)).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with Dyalog; it is your expectations that are in error.

From the earliest days of the language, APL has evaluated expressions *strictly* right-to-left, not left-to-right, and not using the BEDMAS. Your expression `692.4 - 88 - 6.45 - 39.08 - 20 - 53` should be evaluated as though it were written conventionally as `692.4 - (88 - (6.45 - (39.08 - (20 - 53))))`, which will give you the `538.77` that you consider erroneous.